# MS Visual Studio 2015 BEX nvd3d9wrap.dll

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

Возникает следующая ошибка при выполнении некоторых проектов в VS 2013/2015.

```
Сигнатура проблемы:
  Имя события проблемы: BEX
  Имя приложения:   devenv.exe
  Версия приложения:    14.0.25420.1
  Отметка времени приложения:   57685d85
  Имя модуля с ошибкой: nvd3d9wrap.dll
  Версия модуля с ошибкой:  21.21.13.7254
  Отметка времени модуля с ошибкой: 57ac56f9
  Смещение исключения:  0000f3b4
  Код исключения:   c0000417
  Данные исключения:    00000000
  Версия ОС:    6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Код языка:    1049
  Дополнительные сведения 1:    0cee
  Дополнительные сведения 2:    0ceeed89243912e7b2f17f2d2c311358
  Дополнительные сведения 3:    eb42
  Дополнительные сведения 4:    eb42052c3c4c163381ef8d6763cf5c60

Ознакомьтесь с заявлением о конфиденциальности в Интернете:
  [url]http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0419[/url]

Если заявление о конфиденциальности в Интернете недоступно, ознакомьтесь с его локальным вариантом:
  C:\Windows\system32\ru-RU\erofflps.txt
```

Возникает ошибка при выполнении в студии некоторых проектов WinAPI.(Некоторые выполняет в отладке, некоторые - нет). Компилит все проекты, а выполняет не все. Exe-файлы этих не запускающихся проектов ручками запускаются нормально, а в студии не хотят.

Может быть кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это вылет драйвера NVIDIA, вряд ли имеющая отношение к C++ :)
Данная проблема описана [здесь](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5da9dd69-38c3-40b1-9220-7cc51aeec701/crash-after-updating-nvidia-drivers?forum=visualstudiogeneral) (кстати, с полпинка ищется в Интернете...)

Рекомендации по указанному адресу:

If all projects has this issue, please try with following steps to troubleshoot this issue.

- Run Visual Studio in safe mode to prevents all third-party VSPackages from loading when Visual Studio starts, thus ensuring stable execution.
- Reset all settings for your Visual Studio.
- Repair your Visual Studio to check whether the Visual Studio installation is broken when upgrade the NIVIDIA drivers.

Comment: > devenv /SafeMode 
не помогло

Comment: /ResetSetings General - результат тот же

Comment: Ну, чем богаты... :(